# Issue with network app using some browsers

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, sdl, sdl-net

I have simple proxy app, that listens connections from browser on port 4711. Then app sends requests to server (own app) and compares server's version of requested data with local cache and then applies that difference and sends data back to browser.

I'm working till with very simply sites, that contents only home page. But there is working correctly only in IE 10. I tested FF, Chrome, Safari, but they are not working. They are hanging while requests to proxy.

The app is written on C, using SDL, and SDL_Net network functions. Used non-blocking TCP sockets. I'm debugging using VS 2010 and Windows 8.

Please suggest what should I check firstly. I understand i described the problem very briefly, but i can provide additional info (pieces of code etc.) if needed.

Ok. Put some code here.

```
typedef struct _UA_REQUEST
{
    My_string   full_url ;
    uint32_t        url_adler32 ;
    TCPsocket   sock_ua ;
    uint32_t    status_flag ;               // ref Enum STATUS
} UA_REQUEST ;

UA_REQUEST  GLB_ARRAY__UA_REQ[ NUM_UA_SOCK ] ;
TCPsocket   GLB_SOCK_SS={0} , GLB_LSOCK_UA={0} ;


        while( 1 )
        {
            nrdy = SDLNet_CheckSockets(GLB_SOCK_SET, -1 /*1000*/);
            if(nrdy == -1 )
                break ;
            if( !nrdy )
                continue ;

            check_listener_socket() ;
            check_user_agent_sockets() ;
            check_single_stream_socket() ;
        }

    //==================================================================
    //  Check and handle connection request from UA ( user agent )
    //==================================================================

    void check_listener_socket()
    {
        uint32_t index ;
        UA_REQUEST*ar = GLB_ARRAY__UA_REQ ;
        if( !SDLNet_SocketReady( GLB_LSOCK_UA ) )
        {
            puts("check_listener_socket():  GLB_LSOCK_UA is not ready!");
            return ;
        }

        TCPsocket sock_ua = SDLNet_TCP_Accept( GLB_LSOCK_UA ) ; // accept connection from browser

        if( !sock_ua)
        {
            printf("ERR__TCP_Accept: %s\n", SDLNet_GetError());
            goto quit ;
        } else
            printf("Accepted.\n");

        for( index=0 ; (index < NUM_UA_SOCK) ; index++)
            if( STATUS(ar,index) == ST_SOCK_CLOSED )
                break ;
        if( index >= NUM_UA_SOCK )
            return;

        SOCK_UA( ar , index ) = sock_ua;
        STATUS( ar , index )    = ST_SOCK_AVLBL ;
        SDLNet_TCP_AddSocket( GLB_SOCK_SET , SOCK_UA( ar, index ) ) ;

    quit:
        return;
   }

//==================================================================
//  Check and receive data from UA
//==================================================================

void check_user_agent_sockets()
{
    UA_REQUEST *ar = GLB_ARRAY__UA_REQ ;
    uint32_t index ;

    for( index=0 ;  index < NUM_UA_SOCK ; index++)  
    {
        int ready = SDLNet_SocketReady( SOCK_UA(ar,index) );
        if( /*STATUS( ar,index) != ST_SOCK_CLOSED &&*/
            ready /*SDLNet_SocketReady( SOCK_UA(ar,index) ) */
        )
        {
            printf("index =  %i\n", index);
            handle_ua_sock_ready( index ) ;
        }
    }
}

void handle_ua_sock_ready( uint32_t i )
{
    My_string _req_mstr ;
    MY_ALLOC( _req_mstr , MAXLEN )

    byte*request    = _req_mstr.c_str ;
    byte*pcrlf  = NULL ;
    RESET_BUF(request)

    UA_REQUEST*ar = GLB_ARRAY__UA_REQ ;

    //uint32_t 
    int nrcv;   // : Slava
    nrcv = SDLNet_TCP_Recv( SOCK_UA(ar,i) , request , MAXLEN ) ;


    if( nrcv<=0 )
    {
        puts("handle_ua_sock_ready()  before handle_ua_sock_closed");
        handle_ua_sock_closed( ar , i ) ;
        puts("handle_ua_sock_ready()  after handle_ua_sock_closed");
        goto quit;
    }

    puts("1") ;
    if(                     
        ( STATUS(ar,i) == ST_TUNNEL)        
        || (MATCH( request , CONN , strlen(CONN)))  
    )                       
    {                       
        FULL_URL( ar , i ).c_str[0] = 0 ;       
        FULL_URL( ar , i ).len  = 0 ;       
        STATUS( ar , i )        = ST_TUNNEL ;   
        request[nrcv]   = 0 ;           

        send_to_server(TUNNEL_REQ ,request, nrcv, i);   
        goto quit;
    }   
    puts("11") ;
    if( get_hdrs_and_full_url(request, i ,(uint32_t*)&nrcv,pcrlf) == -1 )
    {
        puts("handle_ua_sock_ready()    test 2");
        goto quit ;
    }

    My_string *purl_mstr = &FULL_URL( ar , i ) ;

    log_msg( purl_mstr->c_str , purl_mstr->len , __LINE__ ) ;

    URL_ADLER32( ar, i) = my_adler_32( 1 , purl_mstr->c_str , purl_mstr->len ) ;



            fwrite( FULL_URL(ar,i).c_str , sizeof(byte), FULL_URL(ar,i).len , GLB_REQ_LOG) ;

    puts("111") ;


    CHECK_AND_HANDLE_GET_HEAD_REQ( i , request , nrcv )
    CHECK_AND_HANDLE_UNSUPPORTED(ar,i,request )
    uint32_t uv = nrcv;
    CHECK_AND_HANDLE_POST_OPT_REQ(ar,i,request ,/*nrcv*/ uv)
quit:
    MY_FREE( _req_mstr )
    return ;
}

//==================================================================
//  Check and receive reply from "Server"
//==================================================================

void check_single_stream_socket()
{
    puts("-- before return");
    if( !SDLNet_SocketReady(GLB_SOCK_SS) )
    {

        return ;    

    }
    puts("-- before receive_data_from_server()");
    receive_data_from_server() ;
}

//==================================================================
//
//  receive_data_from_server/0 :: First 4 bytes of "Payload" are eql to length of rest of Payload
// 
//==================================================================

void receive_data_from_server()
{
    My_string payload ;

    MY_ALLOC( payload , MAXLEN )

    int ncnt;   // : Slava
    uint32_t  nreply , req_index , rep_index ;
    uint32_t aallocated, ffreed ;


    byte err[100] ;
    bool bExitFlag = false;

    puts("30001") ;

    payload.len = 0 ;
    if( get_payload(&payload) == -1 )
        goto quit ;
    UA_REQUEST*req_arr  = GLB_ARRAY__UA_REQ ;
    SS_REPLY*rep_arr        = GLB_ARRAY__SS_REPLY ;

    puts("30002") ;

//  printf( "rep_type :: %u \nreq_id :: %u \n" , payload.c_str[0] , SDLNet_Read32( payload.c_str+1 ) ) ;

    uint8_t rep_type = payload.c_str[0] ;

    if( (rep_type == 1)
        || (rep_type == 3)
        || ( rep_type==4 )
    )                   /*ie req_id == req_arr index*/
    {
        puts("30003") ;

        req_index = SDLNet_Read32( payload.c_str+1 ) ;
        nreply  = payload.len-5 ;
        ncnt    = SDLNet_TCP_Send(
                        SOCK_UA( req_arr,req_index)
                        , payload.c_str+5 , nreply
                    ) ;
        if(ncnt < nreply)
        {
            sprintf((char*)err , "ERR__SOCK_WRITE :: bytes to be written: %u ;; actual num:: %u" , nreply , ncnt ) ;
            log_msg(err , strlen((char*)err) , __LINE__ ) ;
            handle_ua_sock_closed( req_arr , req_index ) ;
        }
    }
    else if( payload.c_str[0] == 2 )        /* < req_id == "url_adler32" > */
    {
        puts("30004") ;

        uint32_t url_adler32    = SDLNet_Read32( payload.c_str+1 ) ;

        for( req_index = 0 ; req_index<NUM_UA_SOCK ; req_index++ )
        {
            if(URL_ADLER32( req_arr , req_index) == url_adler32 )
            {

                puts("30005") ;

                My_string reply_mstr ;
                MY_ALLOC( reply_mstr , MAXLEN ) 
                update_cache__and__read_in_mystr(   payload.c_str+5 ,payload.len-5
                                ,&reply_mstr ,req_index
                                ) ;
                nreply = reply_mstr.len ;

                puts("30006") ;

                ncnt = SDLNet_TCP_Send(
                            SOCK_UA( req_arr , req_index)
                            , reply_mstr.c_str              // reply_mstr
                            , nreply
                        ) ;
                if(ncnt < nreply)
                {
                    sprintf((char*)err , "ERR__SOCK_WRITE :: bytes to be written: %u ;; actual num:: %u" , nreply , ncnt ) ;
                    log_msg(err , strlen((char*)err) , __LINE__ ) ;
                    handle_ua_sock_closed( req_arr , req_index ) ;
                }
                else
                    reset_req_arr_element( req_index) ;

                MY_FREE( reply_mstr )
                bExitFlag = true;   // : Slava
                break;
            }
        }


        if (!bExitFlag) 
        {
            for( rep_index = 0 ; rep_index<NUM_SS_REPLY ; rep_index++)
                if(STATUS( rep_arr , rep_index )==ST_EMPTY)
                    break ;
            My_string*pdel_mstr = &(REPLY( rep_arr , rep_index )) ;
            if(pdel_mstr->len)
                pdel_mstr->len = 0 ;
            append( pdel_mstr , payload.c_str+5 , payload.len-5 ) ;

            puts("30007") ;

            STATUS( rep_arr , rep_index ) = ST_OCCUPIED ;
        }

    }   /*</ id_type != "socket"> */
quit:
    MY_FREE( payload )
}
```

I can also add that app does not send even need packets to browser. I used SoftPerfect sniffer for this goal.

Comment: You should provide aditional info, specifically code, expected results and actual results.

Comment: You run a network sniffer and check if the app sends back responses. If it doesn't, you run your app with a debugger and check where unexpected things happen that prevent it from sending back responses. If it does send responses but your browsers just don't see them, then you can either blame a firewall, or blame an incorrect implementation of the HTTP protocol by your app, or blame an incorrect implementation of HTML by your app.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I disabled all firewalls in my PC, including Windows firewall and have same problem still. I think rather problem in code. Do you think may be difference in protocols in different browsers, because IE is working still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers, specially to @n.m.. I used Fiddler and SoftPerfect sniffers to spot my bug. There is error in my code.

Thanks all,
Vyacheslav